# Old 2005 ford focus wont start and flickering guages

Tags: ford, focus, wont-stay-running

So I came home from india and the battery was dead anyway got someone I know to come jump it with me and it got me on the road for about 20 mins and then car died again. At this point I just wanted to go home so got taxi. Day 2 I went back to the car to give it more juice this time I thought yesterday it was night time and I had lights on I didn't give alternator enough time to generate power for the lights to be on. So we juiced it up and the car lasted about 1 hour this time and the car died again. I thought right I'm charge the battery with a trickle charger in the house and see if it's okay after this. Anyway I charged it and took partner to work 10 mins and car died again. So I bought another battery. So put new battery in and it worked for a day before dieing again. So I just took the battery home to charge it again but it's showing full battery!! So I thought it's not the battery and it's not the alternator what the hell is it? Symptoms when it dies:

1. Car drops revs from 800 slowly to stall.
2. When trying to start the car again the gauges shudder the indicators.
3. When starting it also looks like it's losing power.

Could it be the fuel injectors instead?

Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When you start the car, see if you can keep it from stalling by keeping foot on the gas pedal, keeping it running. if you can keep it running doing this, clean your throttle body.